# Por que o 'getJson' não funciona?

Tags: jquery, json

Meu arquivo *select-menu.json* está assim:

```
{
    value: "1",
    descricao: "1"
},
{
    value: "2",
    descricao: "2"
},
{
    value: "3",
    descricao: "3"
};
```

E estou tentando obtê-lo dessa forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON( "js/json/select-menu.json", function( data ) {
       alert(data);
    })
});
```

Porém não está alertando o `data`. Coloquei o projeto no servidor e o caminho para o arquivo está correto.

Comment: no lugar do `alert(data);` coloca `console.log(data);` e veja oque retorna.

Comment: não retorna nada também.

Comment: Apertando F12 no navegador você entra na barra de ferramentas onde pode ir no console do navegador verificar se houve erros.

Comment: não há nenhum erro.

Answer (score 2):

Adicione um `error handler` para capturar erros:

Nesse exemplo, usamos o método `fail()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "js/json/select-menu.json", function(data) {
      console.log( "success", data );
    })
      .fail(function(textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error " + textStatus, errorThrown);
      })

});
```

Com isso, poderá ver o erro que está bastante óbvio.

O conteúdo do arquivo `select-menu.json` possui um formato `json` inválido.

Corrija com o seguinte formato:

```
[
{
    "value": 1,
    "descricao": 1
},
{
    "value": 2,
    "descricao": 2
},
{
    "value": 3,
    "descricao": 3
}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

voce devia, em primeiro lugar, saber exactamente o que é o formato "JSON"...

1. `value: "1",` deve ser escrito como `"value": "1",`
2. JSON é um formato, não existe `;`
3. o que escreveu é um `array`, para tal devia de ser embutido em `[]` ou seja `[ { "value":"1","descricao":"2"}, ... ]`

use um Online Parser para ver se a syntax é a correcta, por exemplo: http://json.parser.online.fr/

o texto correcto no seu ficheiro devia ser escrito como:

```
[
  {
    "value": "1",
    "descricao": "1"
  },
  {
    "value": "2",
    "descricao": "2"
  },
  {
    "value": "3",
    "descricao": "3"
  }
]
```

Apenas para adicionar um pouco mais de informcão sobre o formato, as variaveis têm de estar delimitadas por double quote `"`, apenas os valores é que não...

```
"value": "3"
```

faz com que o `value` tenha o valor de uma string com conteúdo `3`

```
"value": 3
```

faz com que o `value` tenha o valor de um numero com conteúdo `3`, ou seja, no caso so seu exemplo, e imaginando que o objecto tem a variavél `data`:

o resultado de `data[0].value + data[1].value` será de `12` e não `3`

Answer (score 1):

para usar o " . " você deve ter um json object:
da uma olhada depois na documentação a diferença entre json string, e json object na biblioteca do jquery.

você tem que usar o .parseJson();    exemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.getJSON( "js/json/select-menu.json", function( data ) {

       var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

       alert(obj.value);
       // como você tem uma lista, provavelmente irá usar um index para
       // obj.value[0] ou obj.value[1]
    })
});
```